# CheckSelfPermission always return permission denied

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, runtime-permissions

In Android M (Android 6) I'm using the method `ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission()`.

The result of this method is always "Permission Denied" even when I manually 
enabled the requested permission in the app settings.

What can be the cause for this?

```
  int smsPermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(AuthActivity.this, Manifest.permission_group.SMS);

  if (smsPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) 
  {
      dialog.setCancelable(false);
      dialog.setMessage("dialog content");
      dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
      {
          @Override
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
          {
             ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(AuthActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, Constants.REQUEST_SMS_PERMISSION);
             dialogInterface.dismiss();
          }
       });
       dialog.show();
   }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`checkSelfPermission()` takes a permission (e.g., `SEND_SMS`), not a permission group.